# Large number of dust inputs sum to nice round numbers. How and what wallet used?

Tags: transactions, wallet, dust

Consider the bitcointalk donation address `17RTTUAiiPqUTKtEggJPec8RxLMi2n9EZ9`.

This has many incoming transactions with large number of dust inputs (hundreds) that sum to nice rounded numbers as in the following examples:

[ba930f48aae32b8915a6e413ed297060291fec7fc916cf57b0751e0f77c41df2](https://blockchain.info/tx/ba930f48aae32b8915a6e413ed297060291fec7fc916cf57b0751e0f77c41df2) (inputs sum to 0.05)

[c0f25cc0f008ac935b3a38fecdea42e062ba3e3e7395161a2ad1b38754ee31c0](https://blockchain.info/tx/c0f25cc0f008ac935b3a38fecdea42e062ba3e3e7395161a2ad1b38754ee31c0) (inputs sum to 0.05)

[1f4e0b21e6edd0dc1148116200426f390880e3e33ae0723de8415836874f7a3e](https://blockchain.info/tx/1f4e0b21e6edd0dc1148116200426f390880e3e33ae0723de8415836874f7a3e) (inputs sum to 0.5)

These can't be coincidences. What wallet is being used here? Does it solve the "[subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)" problem for each transaction to ensure that the sums are round numbers? I know the problem won't be hard for such small sizes but still needs solving.

Answer (score 1):

Another explanation might be that one of the input transactions is intentionally created to cause the sum to be a round number.

Comment: I believe that's the question. Selecting a large number of inputs to perfectly sum  a round figure is non-trivial.

Comment: Why would someone do that? And out of curiosity who is the sender?